# Package Optmatch Error Message

Tags: r

I am attempting to use the **pair** function in the **R** package **optmatch** on some sample data:

```
> tmp
  id dose        Pred
1  1    2  0.08494142
2  1    2 -0.02784262
3  1    2 -0.05284574
4  1    2 -0.07428686
5  1    3  0.04335151
```

which can be re-created using this code:

```
tmp <- data.frame(id = rep(1,5), dose = c(rep(2,4),3), 
                  Pred = c(0.08494142, -0.02784262,
                           -.05284574, -0.07428686,
                           0.04335151))
```

When I run the code:

```
pair(x = tmp$Pred, z = tmp$dose, data=tmp, remove.unmatchables = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in toZ(z) : Treatment indicator must have exactly 2 levels not 1
```

However, as can be seen from the data frame, the treatment indicator variable **dose** has only two levels:  2 or 3.

Using function **getAnywhere** I am able to print out the section of the function **toZ** (which is called by **pair**) that presumably generates the error:

```
> getAnywhere(toZ)
[Lines omitted]
function (x) 
{
[Lines of code omitted]
if (length(unique(x)) != 2) {
        stop(paste("Treatment indicator must have exactly 2 levels not", 
            length(unique(x))))
}
```

To confirm my suspicions, I run the following:

```
> length(unique(tmp$dose))
[1] 2
```

confirming that the treatment indicator does indeed have exactly 2 levels.  I am quite perplexed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is suspect that the error comes from the `remove.unmatchables = TRUE`. Your singleton, treatment observation is being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/markmfredrickson/optmatch/issues/124) in optmatch. We have a fix that will be in the next released version. For now, the work around is to construct a logical variable from your numeric treatment indicator. E.g.

```
tmp$dose2 <- tmp$dose == 3
```